# How do I print a Map of 25 objects to a 5x5 table in angular?

Tags: json, angular

How do I print a Map of 25 keys to a 5x5 table in angular ?

Inupt : Map<String, String>

Sample map below

> {   "one": "odd",   "two": "even",    .    .    .    "twentyfive" :
> "odd"   }

---

Below is the Expected output, but with loops.

```
<tr><td>one</td><td>one</td><td>one</td><td>one</td><td>one</td></tr>
<tr><td>six</td>...........<td>ten</td></tr>
<tr><td>eleven</td>........<td>fifteen</td>></tr>
<tr><td>sixteen</td>........<td>twenty</td></tr>
<tr><td>twentyone</td>........<td>twentyfive</td></tr>
```

Comment: Please share your json data format

Comment: @VimalPatel thanks for the reply, there is no json. All I want is to iterate and print the key of the map which has 25 entries into a 5 row and 5 column table.

Map<String, String>

Comment: What I mean by json is your data format.

Comment: Incoming data is Map<String, String>

I need output like this, but with loops

<tr><td>one<td><td>two<td><td>three<td><td>four<td><td>five<td><tr>
<tr><td>six<td>..............<td><tr>
<tr><td>eleven<td>..............<td><tr>
<tr><td>sixteen<td>..............<td><tr>
<tr><td>twentyone<td><td>one<td><td>one<td><td>one<td><td>twentyfive<td><tr>

Answer (score 2):

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let x of map | keyvalue">
    <tr>
        <td>{{x.key}}</td>
        <td>{{x.value}}</td>
    </tr>
</ng-container>
```

[KeyValuePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe)

if you need to display this in chunks of 5 elements I suggest you split it

[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/map-chunks-example?file=src/app/app.component.ts/app/app.component.html)

Comment: 1. This will not print data in the table in a 5x5 format 2. Row order is not maintained while displaying the table.

Comment: I modified the example so the order is maintained

Answer (score 1):

Store the json in a 2D array using the below logic, thereby it becomes easier to iterate over it in the template.

```js
json = {
    one: 'odd', two: 'even', three: 'odd', four: 'even', five: 'odd',
    six: 'even', seven: 'odd', eight: 'even', nine: 'odd', ten: 'even',
    eleven: 'odd', twelve: 'even', thirteen: 'odd', fourteen: 'even', fifteen: 'odd',
    sixteen: 'even', seventeen: 'odd', eigthteen: 'even',
    nineteen: 'odd', 
    twenty: 'even'
  };

res = [];

let i = 0, j = 0;
for (let obj in json) {
   if (j % 5 !== 4) {
      if (res[i]) {
         res[i].push(obj);
      } else {
         res[i] = [];
         res[i].push(obj);
      }
      j++;
    } else {
       res[i].push(obj);
       i++;
       j = 0;
    }
}

console.log(res)
```

And on the template:

```
<table>
    <tr *ngFor="let e1 of res | keyvalue">
        <td *ngFor="let e2 of e1.value | keyvalue">
            {{ e2.value | json}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```